# add erb tag to link_to class in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a link class like

```
link_to( class: 'btn_download<%= index %>')
```

from a .each_with_index model call

```
Model.each_with_index do |m, index|
```

but it throws an error
[image]

and when i try with #{index} it just adds #{index} to the class name instead of dynamically adding 'index'

[image]

Comment: Please post an error in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noticed there are some issues in your code. Please find below the code snippet example I wrote similar to your case which will help you to fix your issue

```
<% User.all.each_with_index do |m, index| %>
  <%= link_to users_path, class: "btn_download#{index}" do %>
    <span class="fa fa-sign-out"></span>
      Download
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So instead of using `'btn_download <%= index %>'` try `"btn_download#{index}"`.

Also, Use double quotes

`class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm download_btn#{index}"`

instead

`class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm download_btn#{index}'`

Please let me know if you have any confusion in this.

Comment: awesome thanks.. i tried this but was using single quotes instead of double

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wrap your link around an icon, use the following syntax:

```
<%= link_to ..._path(...) do %>
  <i class="fa fa-spin fa spinner"></i>
<% end %>
```

You have to append a `do` onto the link to and then close the block with an `end`. And just put whatever inbetween (icon or image or div).